# Mobx changing observable values outside of action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, mobx

I'm getting the following error:

```
proxyConsole.js:54 Error: [mobx] Invariant failed: Since strict-mode is enabled, changing observed observable values outside actions is not allowed. Please wrap the code in an `action` if this change is intended. Tried to modify: ObservableObject@1.items
    at invariant (mobx.module.js:2326)
    at fail (mobx.module.js:2321)
    at checkIfStateModificationsAreAllowed (mobx.module.js:2890)
    at ObservableValue../node_modules/mobx/lib/mobx.module.js.ObservableValue.prepareNewValue (mobx.module.js:796)
    at setPropertyValue (mobx.module.js:1673)
    at Object.set [as items] (mobx.module.js:1641)
    at Store.js:41
    at <anonymous>
```

But I am wrapping the function in an `action` so I'm a little confused:

```
import { observable, useStrict, action } from 'mobx';
import Services from './Services';

// ...

getAllTodos: action(() => {

    Services.getAllTodos()
    .then((response) => {

        state.items = response.data;

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });

}),
```

Services.js

```
// ...

getAllTodos () {
    return axios.get(root + '/items/');
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function that alters the observables needs to be wrapped in `action`, so use it on the callback as well:

```
getAllTodos: action(() => {

  Services.getAllTodos()
  .then(action((response) => {
    state.items.replace(response.data);
  })).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
})
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. isn't that exactly what @Tiwaz89 did and it still didn't work?

Comment: @oriharel Notice how Tiwaz89's `getAllTodos` method is an action, but the function given to `then` is also an action in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the MobX docs [here](https://mobx.js.org/best/actions.html#writing-asynchronous-actions):

> The action wrapper / decorator only affects the currently running function, not functions that are scheduled (but not invoked) by the current function! This means that if you have a setTimeout, promise.then or async construction, and in that callback some more state is changed, those callbacks should be wrapped in action as well!

Thus, you'd have to wrap the scheduled `promise.then` here in an action as well, apart from the parent function. (Note that you'd only be able to use the `@action` on the class-level function)

There are two ways of doing it:

```
action(
  asyncFunction().then(
    action((args) => {
      // Your function body here
    })
  )
)
```

--or--

Use the `@action.bound`:

```
@action
asyncFunction().then(
  yourStateModifyingFunction();
)

@action.bound
yourStateModifyingFunction() {
  // Your function body here
}
```